# Is the LM324 safe to be used as a comparator with a supply of 3.3V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, operational-amplifier

The datasheet mentions the supply voltage range to be from 3V to 30V, but I'm concerned about wacky performace at a voltage close to the lowest required. All the characteristics in the datasheet are specified for a VCC of 5V.

I'll be using the device as a simple Schmitt trigger.

Comment: Another option is to consider the low voltage version of it such as https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm321lv.pdf

Comment: Depends. Are you ok with the (V+) – 1.5 max input range? At 3.3 V input, you can only have input signals up to 1.7 V.

Comment: @winny Nope. My input voltage can go up to 3V. How did you find this information?

Comment: Page 8 under Input voltage rage in https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm324.pdf

Comment: @EarthLord Looks good. Just concerned if this is a cheap, widely available part. Can't find it on element14.

Comment: @winny Wow, I don't know how I missed that. My bad. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @winny What is likely to happen if the voltage goes above 1.7V. Not gonna try it, just curious.

Comment: You are most welcome. LM324 is really old with big limitations compared to modern alternatives, but you are correct on availability for it.

Comment: Will probably work a bit further as Vcc-1.5 V is worst case guaranteed value, but delay will probably increase and I can imagine offset also suffers. Some comparators will invert their behavior if you goo too far overrange. I can't recall if LM324 is one of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149184/discussion-between-nottherealfaraday-and-winny).

Answer (score 1):

From information in the comments, if you have 0-5 V input range yet need to interface towards 3.3 V GPIOs, you can use a comparator with open collector (or drain) output to "shift" from 5 to 3.3 V.

LM139 is a popular choice but there are hundreds to choose from. Pick one which satisfies your offset voltage, input range and speed requirements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ9hRs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are no Vcc and GND ports on the comparator symbol so you just have to imagine them. The schematic is very generic, just to give you and idea how to use a 3.3 V pull-up on the output.

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine as a slow precision comparator given limitations on input voltage range and output swing. Also take note of the slew rate, which applies when it is used as a ST.

The input stage is actually almost identical to that of the LM339 comparator, a device of similar vintage. No weirdness provided at least one input is within the input range. Phase reversal is possible if you apply inputs significantly below ground.

Answer (score 0):

> What is likely to happen if the voltage goes above 1.7V. Not gonna try it, just curious.

Here is what happened ...

[image]

One can note that inputs are ok ... Output is lower, 1.2 V (~ 3.3 V -2 V).